# Backlash in email, still Magento validate-email don't respond

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, form-validation

```
/js/prototype/validation.js

["validate-email","Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.",function(e){return Validation.get("IsEmpty").test(e)||/^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(e)}]
```

The type of email in which backlash is there e.g. john/smith@domain.com, john#smith#@domain.com or john*smoth@domain.com are not showing error for validation of emails.

What I can do to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a new javascript file and place it in /js folder.**

For example : js/validation-override.js

```
Validation.add("validate-email","Please enter a valid email address. For example john_smith@domain.com.",function(e){return Validation.get("IsEmpty").test(e)||/^([\w-\.]+)@(([[0-9]‌​{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[‌​0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]‌​+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4‌​}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?‌​)$/i.test(e)})
```

**Add this code inside your theme layout xml file app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/layout/page.xml :**

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>validation-override.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

You can find more information here : http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: Doesn't work john/smith@domain.com, john#smith#@domain.com still validating..

Comment: Are you sure your overriden JS file is loaded? Maybe browser cache?

Comment: Yeah, your code is working but it doesn't achieve what I wanted. I just don't understand how to avoid special characters in the names except "fullstop" and "underscore"

Comment: For what you want to achieve you have to change the regular expression in **js/validation-override.js**

Comment: Let's say I don't want to allow John/Smit@domain.com type or John*Smith@domain, how can I achieve this by changing regular expression?

Comment: In your initial request you don't mention * character, please update it.

Comment: Ok sure. Please check it out, I added now..

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it doesn't solve my issue. I found some other solution. I still believe you solved my half answer. Can you please edit your coding to this      -->            Validation.add("validate-email","Please enter a valid email address. For example john_smith@domain.com.",function(e){return Validation.get("IsEmpty").test(e)||/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/i.test(e)})

Comment: Edited, thank you.